# Reducing a surjective continuous function to a bijective continuous function.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{S})$ be two topological spaces and let $f:X\to Y$ be continuous and onto (surjective).

Is there any $A\subseteq X$ such that $f|A$ is bijective and continuous?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes (assuming the axiom of choice!). Just take any subset $A$ such that $f|_A$ is a bijection (i.e. *choose* one element from each set $f^{-1}(y)$ --they're all non-empty since $f$ is onto), the restriction is automatically continuous too.

Comment: if so $\mathbb{C}$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but $\mathbb{R}$ has only one connected proper subset.

Comment: @CutieKrait: How do you conclude that it is homeomorphic?  There is no reason for the inverse map to be continuous.

Comment: I think you may be confusing "continuous bijection" with "homeomorphism" in your above comment, @CutieKrait. Did you mean to ask the question with "homeomorphism" in place of "continuous bijection"? If so, I have no good answer. :P

Comment: so the continuous mapping of a not-connected set can be connected!?

Comment: Sure, @CutieKrait, consider the function $f(x)=x^2$ with domain $[-2,-1] \cup [0,1]$!

Comment: @CutieKrait: Recall that a continuous bijection is not necessary a homeomorphism.

Comment: @CutieKrait constant functions are great at chasing away topological misconceptions.

Comment: @Cutie: Every separable complete metric space is the continuous image of the irrational numbers, which is a totally disconnected space.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: A more drastic and much simpler example of the same sort of thing is that every space X is a continuous image of the discrete space with |X| points (even by a continuous bijection!). :)

Comment: about continuous surjective function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$, I think $A$ must be totally disconnected.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is equivalent to the axiom of choice. The axiom of choice can be formulated as follows: given any surjective function $f:A\to B$ there exists a section $s:B\to A$, that is $f(s(b))=b$ holds for all $b\in B$.

So, assuming the axiom of choice given a continuous surjective function $f:X\to Y$ let $s:Y\to X$ be a section. Then it follows immediately that taking $A$ to be the image of $s$ is a subset of $X$ such that $f$ restricted to it is bijectiv. Since the restriction of any continuous map is still continuous we are done.

In the other direction, assume the property in the question holds. Given a function $f:X\to Y$ consider the indiscrete topologies on $X,Y$. Then $f$ is continuous and thus there is a set $A\subseteq X$ such that $f|_A$ is bijective. Now construct a section $s:Y\to X$ by the rule $s(y)=(f|_A)^{-1}(y)$. $s$ is continuous since the topologies are indiscrete and further it is clearly a section.

This shows that the question is actually not at all a question of topology but of set theory.